# celerybeat shutdown - initscript order?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, reboot, django-celery

I'm trying to setup rabbitmq/celery/django-celery/django so that it is "rebootproof", i.e. it all just comes back up by itself. Everything seems to work fine except this:

When I reboot, all services get started, but it seems celeryd is started before rabbitmq, and celerybeat gets subsequently terminated because it can't connect (?):

```
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,128: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@inquire has started.
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,130: INFO/Beat] child process calling self.run()
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,131: INFO/Beat] Celerybeat: Starting...
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,134: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2 seconds...
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,688: INFO/Beat] process shutting down
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,689: WARNING/Beat] Process Beat:
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,689: WARNING/Beat] Traceback (most recent call last):
...
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,756: WARNING/Beat] File "/home/inquire/inquire.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 220, in create_transport
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,760: WARNING/Beat] return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,761: WARNING/Beat] File "/home/inquire/inquire.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 58, in __init__
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,761: WARNING/Beat] self.sock.connect((host, port))
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,761: WARNING/Beat] File "<string>", line 1, in connect
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,761: WARNING/Beat] error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
[2011-06-14 00:48:35,761: INFO/Beat] process exiting with exitcode 1
[2011-06-14 00:48:37,137: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 4 seconds...
```

On Ubuntu, I installed rabbitmq-server with apt, django-celery with pip into my virtualenv, then I symlinked the "celeryd" initscript I got from https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/contrib/debian/init.d in /etc/init.d, configured it in /etc/default/celeryd to use the django celeryd from my virtualenv, and made it "rebootproof" via (maybe "defaults" is the problem?)

```
update-rc.d celeryd defaults
```

Rather than running celeryd and celerybeat with separate initscripts, I just configured celeryd to include Beat (maybe that's the problem?):

```
CELERYD_OPTS="-v 2 -B -s celery -E"
```

Any pointers how to solve this issue?

If I

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart
```

there are no complaints:

```
[2011-06-14 00:54:29,157: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@inquire has started.
[2011-06-14 00:54:29,161: INFO/Beat] child process calling self.run()
[2011-06-14 00:54:29,162: INFO/Beat] Celerybeat: Starting...
```

but I need to eliminate the need for any manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

celerybeat's dependency on the broker service was indeed the issue.
Rather than installing the initscript with

```
update-rc.d celeryd defaults
```

with the rabbitmq-server script being installed as sequence number 20 for start and kill, celerybeat's dependency must be resolved by explicitly starting it after (and killing it before) rabbitmq-server by using

```
update-rc.d celeryd defaults 21 19
```

NB: I've actually opted for the separate celerybeat service instead of the -B invocation, and only did 21 19 for *that* script, i.e. the one with the problem.

Comment: I still find that celerybeat could benefit from having the same retry-behaviour as celeryd, and filed a corresponding feature request: https://github.com/ask/celery/issues/419

Comment: FYI this behaviour has now been implemented for celerybeat: https://github.com/ask/celery/commit/8ac05a37e2a5ba9099b5ca21b17d138be4c24222 (two hours after reporting - wow!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not in celery it self but in your script, probably when celeryd starts the broker is not listening yet.
I'm using almost your same command and I don't have any issue, launch the celeryd script with -B option is not wrong.
I think that on your reboot script you have to wait for rabbitmq complete restart before launch celeryd, maybe with test of connection too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems celeryd itself doesn't seem to mind that the broker isn't listening yet (Trying again in 2 seconds..., Trying again in 4 seconds...). celerybeat however gets terminated, and I thought maybe running celerybeat as a service (as opposed to the -B "spin-off") will get me a similar retry-behaviour. Will try a few things.